# How to retrieve vCard in xmpp , which delegate method and flow is use for get vCard in cocoa os x app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xmppframework

I have implement xmpp framework in my `cocoa os x` application. currently am working on `vCard`. i have done work on set all required field's data of login user and it stored successfully, but i have no proper solution for how to get login user's stored `vcard` and am not aware of it. Please give me solution for this problem. i have been suffering for this from last 3 days. help me as soon as

Thanx in advance

i have used below code to set `vCard` field

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            dispatch_async(queue, ^
        {

                XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage *xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
                XMPPvCardTempModule *xmppvCardTempModule = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc] initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
                [xmppvCardTempModule  activate:[self xmppStream]];

                XMPPvCardTemp *myvCardTemp = [xmppvCardTempModule myvCardTemp];
                if (!myvCardTemp)
                {
                    NSXMLElement *vCardXML = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"vCard" xmlns:@"vcard-temp"];
                    XMPPvCardTemp *newvCardTemp = [XMPPvCardTemp vCardTempFromElement:vCardXML];
                    [newvCardTemp setName:@"vCard"];
                    [newvCardTemp setNickname:lbl.stringValue]; 
                    [newvCardTemp setFormattedName:@"abc"];
                    [newvCardTemp setDesc:lbl_abt.stringValue]; 
                    [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:newvCardTemp];
                }
                else
                {
                    [myvCardTemp setName:@"vCard"];
                    [myvCardTemp setNickname:lbl.stringValue]; 
                    [myvCardTemp setFormattedName:@"abc"];
                    [myvCardTemp setDesc:lbl_abt.stringValue]; 
                    [xmppvCardTempModule updateMyvCardTemp:myvCardTemp];
                }

            });
    }
```

And i also tried below code to retrieve vCard

```
    /* XMPPvCardTempModule *xmppvCardTempModule;
        XMPPvCardTemp *vCard =[xmppvCardTempModule vCardTempForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"xxxx"] shouldFetch:YES];
     NSLog(@"V CARD :%@",vCard.nickname);*/

    XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage* xmppvCardStorage = [XMPPvCardCoreDataStorage sharedInstance];
    XMPPvCardTempModule* m = [[XMPPvCardTempModule alloc]initWithvCardStorage:xmppvCardStorage];
    [m fetchvCardTempForJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:@"xxxx"]ignoreStorage:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",xmppvCardStorage.description);
```

Please suggest me proper way to solve this problem :